# How to make BaggingRegressor repeatable

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, neural-network, ensemble-learning

Can someone tell me why despite a high number of bootstrap samples, the results vary a lot from two launches of this code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

estimator =  BaggingRegressor(MLPRegressor(),max_samples =10000,max_features=6)
X_train = X_train[['zkurt','zmean','zscale','zshape','zskew','zvar1']]
y_train = y_train[['vary']]
X_test  = X_test[['zkurt','zmean','zscale','zshape','zskew','zvar1']]
y_test  = y_test[['vary']]
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
y_predict = estimator.predict(X_test)
r2=estimator.score(X_test, y_test.values.ravel())
```

the predictions and the r2 vary a lot from one launche to another.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't get your code to run. What is `estimator`, `X`, 'y', and `skf`

Comment: I added the first part of code (unitil skf.get...). to be launched only once.

Comment: I simplified the code to remove the cross validation part, it is now more simple to re-use

Comment: Just set the ```random_state``` argument in boths components.

Comment: Hi sacha, I dont want to fix the random seed. my opinion is that randomness will not impact the results when the number of bootstrap samples reach a very high level

Comment: Just try it to observe that your assumption is probably wrong (especially because of MLPs non-convex nature and random-init).

Comment: I am aware about it but I am compating bagging on SPSS Modeler and the bagging function of sklearn. with SPSS modeler results results don't vary significantly when I modify the random seed. in sklearn, with the same number of boots, I get a verty different results with two different random seeds